# Check two async boolean variables and call a method if both are satisfied

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

How could I improve this method of rendering only when both variables are met as **true**, to allow the `renderFilters()` method to be called:

These two variables are filled asynchronously through 2 API methods:

```
//getManager() 
this.isLoadingManager = true;
//getPdiPOrganization()
this.isLoadingPdiOrganization = true;

  promiseRender() {
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.isLoadingManager && this.isLoadingPdiOrganization) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                this.renderFilters();
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    this.renderFilters();
                }, 5000)
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

The problem is that it's very slow... it's calling long after the APIs are called...
Maybe some feature of angular itself, if anyone has a better solution...

```
const observable = forkJoin({
        loading1:this.isLoadingManager,
        loading2:this.isLoadingPdiOrganization
      });
      observable.subscribe({
        next: (results) => {
            const obs1Val = results[0];
            const obs2Val = results[1];
            if (obs1Val && obs2Val) {
                this.renderFilters();
            }
          }
      })
```

Or:

```
   const myObservable = Observable.of(this.isLoadingManager && this.isLoadingPdiOrganization);
                const myObserver = {
                   next: (result: Boolean) => this.renderFilters(),
                };
                myObserver.next(true);
                myObservable.subscribe(myObserver);
```

**Adding the methods:**

```
 getManager() {
            if (this.fromAdminPage && localStorage.getItem('_receivers_pdi')) {
                this.meetingService.getIsManager()
                    .subscribe(res => {
                        this.showPdiToastNotification = res;
                        this.isLoadingManager = true;
                    });
            }
     }

getPdiPOrganization() {

        const url = this.publicEndpoint ? 'current/organization/pdi/configuration' : 'api/current/organization/pdi/configuration';

        const requestOptions = {
            params: new CustomHttpParams({ isPublicTokenUrl: this.publicEndpoint })
        };

        this.http.get<any>(url, requestOptions).subscribe(resp => {
            this.isLoadingPdiOrganization = true;
            this.pdiOrgConfig = resp || {};
            this.updatePdiReferenceType(this.pdiOrgConfig);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Add the code of "These two variables are filled asynchronously through 2 API methods"

Comment: Makes more sense to make your isLoading variables promises, then do `Promise.all([managerLoadingPromise, PdiOrganizationLoadingPromise]).then(() => this.renderFilters())`

Comment: @TrevorDixon, I had already tried that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forkjoin` to subscribe to two observables at the same time. I would stick with using RxJs operators for cases like these. You can read more about `forkJoin` [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin).

```js
forkJoin([obs1, obs2]).subscribe({
  next: (results) => {
    const obs1Val = results[0];
    const obs2Val = results[1];
    if (obs1Val && obs2Val) {
      this.renderFilters();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I how I apply this in my case, I did not understand how this would be implemented.

Comment: I had already tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share your code using codesandbox or stackblitz ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fork-join-example-angular-io7hpe?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I made this stackblitz to help understand how forkJoin works.